# How can I add a download link to files in my Digitalocean Space in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean

I'm trying to create a download link/button in my Rails app so that users can download files from my Digitalocean Space. I want to be able to click a download button on my show page and download the file. Here is what I've tried s far:

samples_controller.rb

```
def show
  @sample = Sample.find(params[:id])
  data = open(@sample.audio_url) 
  @sample_download = send_data data.read, filename: @sample.audio.metadata["filename"], type: @sample.audio.metadata["mime_type"], disposition: 'inline' 
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Download Sample", @sample_download %>
```

When I load the show page this opens a page that plays the audio file. What I want is to see my show template as normal and be bale to click a link to download the file. Maybe I should have a separate `download_sample` method, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger download on browser side using the `download` attribute on an `<a>` tag.

All you need is something like `<a href="http://linktofile.com/audio.mp3" download>Download</a>` and user can click on the link to download.

Using the Rails helper, you can do `<%= link_to "Download", @sample.audio_url, download: true %>`

Comment: That still just opens a page that plays the audio file, rather than staying on the show page and downloading the file.

Comment: Modern browsers should respect the `download` attribute. If that doesn't work, you might need to check if your HTML output is correct.

You can check [W3school's example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download)

Answer (score 0):

Hi for content from another website make sure the link is a direct link.
If the data you want to download is from active storage take a look at  `rails_blob_path` ([here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html))
.

In your model

```
Class Sample < ApplicationRecord
     has_one_attached :data
end
```

In your controller

```
  class SampleController < ApplicationController

    def show
     @sample = Sample.find(params[:id])
     @sample_download =  rails_blob_path(@sample.data, disposition: 'attachment')
    end
  end
```

In your views

```
<%=link_to "Download", @sample_download %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm actually using Shrine to upload to DO Spaces, not Active Storage.